# When your API is not ready - React + Redux + Axios

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, axios

This question may be vague, but I thought would help organize my thoughts:

I am setting up the Redux store for a project. Along with the store setup I am setting up an endpoint I have the swagger file for. However, the API is not live just yet. I was wondering how do I set this up with test data in the meantime so when the API is ready, I am able to quickly update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define a `Client` class or object that interacts with your API.  Maybe it has specific functions like `.getUser(id)` or maybe they are move vague like `.getEntity('user', id)`.  This provides a layer of abstraction so that instead of calling `axios.get('my-api/users/${id}')` in your thunk actions you can call `client.getUser(id)`.

You will have two separate versions of a `Client` that fit the same interface (this is a lot easier to enforce if using typescript).  One will query your actual API while the other just returns mock data.  Since they both act the same, it should be easy to switch from one to the other when you are ready.  You will have some file where you create and export a `client` variable.

```
export const client = new APIClient();
```

or

```
export const client = new MockClient();
```

When you import this `client` to use in other files, it shouldn't matter which one it is because they both share the same `Client` interface.